# C++ Builder xe2 & Google Maps api

Tags: c++, google-maps-api-3, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

Can some one point me in the right direction.

I would like to create a C++ application that uses google maps.

I need to be able to do the following

1. Add markers.
2. Calculate distance between markers.
3. Work out long/lat from address.
4. Get address from long/lat.
5. Get address from mouse click on map.

I've seen some components that do this but they are abit pricy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using GMLib found at the following site

https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/

so far it has done everything i have needed.

Comment: seems this project is now closed source can still be found here https://github.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1. I've switched to TMS WebGMaps https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/webgmaps.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if this will help you, but [Delphi & Google Maps API V3](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/) is the first part of a multi part series on the same blog about using Google Maps API V3 in Delphi. Even if you don't know Delphi that well, you can see the names of components that are used.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, had already seed that but wasn't much help, i tried so stuff from there but it didn't work.  be nice if there was a guide from downloading the api right through to you first simple user of it.